# AS3 Current Scene name for if else statement?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I'm building a quick flash presentation, navigating with the up and down arrows but need to create an if else statement using the current scene's name.

I have 10 scenes named 01 - 10 but from 7 to 10 are only accessible by from a hidden button and need to find a way to loop the navigate from 01- 06 using the scene name for example:

```
if scene name = 04 {
   go to nextScene();
} else if scene name = 05 {
   go to nextScene();
} else if scene name = 06 {
   go to scene 02
}
```

I have all working apart from the if else statement as it goes to next scene with the up arrow but continues up to 10 when I need to go to 6 and start again.

Any help would be great?

Thanks,

Thomas.

Comment: I presume that is just pseudo code? That would not compile in flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a couple of functions, use one for your key handler and the other for the hidden button like:

```
function standardScenes(sceneName)
    {
        switch(sceneName)
        {
            case 01:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 02:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 03:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 04:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 05:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 06:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;
        }
    }

    function hiddenScenes(sceneName)
    {
        switch(sceneName)
        {
            case 07:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 08:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 09:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;

            case 10:
                gotoAndPlay(sceneName);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code..

```
stop();
import flash.events.Event;
var no:Number = 0;

btn_up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, up);
function up(e:MouseEvent){
no = no + 1;
getScene(no);
}

btn_down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, down);
function down(e:MouseEvent){
no = no - 1;
getScene(no);
}
function getScene(num:Number){
    if(no <= 0){
        no = 0;
    }
    if(no == 1){
        gotoAndStop(1,"Scene " + no);
    }
    if(no == 2){
        gotoAndStop(1,"Scene " + no);
    }
    //continue here...
}
```